# How to remove elements from an XML with an xpath as the input in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns1:Student xmlns:ns1="http://test1.org/test1" xmlns:ns2="http://test2.org/test2" xmlns:ns3="http://test3.org/test3" xmlns:ns4="http://test4.org/test4">
    <ns2:Details>
        <ns3:Number>12</ns3:Number>
        <ns3:Name>Rosh</ns3:Name>
    </ns2:Details>
    <ns2:Address>
        <ns3:Number>45</ns3:Number>
        <ns3:City>Blore</ns3:City>
    </ns2:Address>
</ns1:Student>
```

I am using an XSLT 1.0 processor.
How do I remove just the node **Number** under **Details** (`ns1:Student/n2:Details/ns3:Number`)?

This is what has worked for me as of now..

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:param name="ElemToDelete" select="'/ns1:Student/ns2:Details/ns3:Number'"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ns1:Student/ns2:Details/ns3:Number"/>
```

But I need to change it in such a way that I can pass a variable which contains the xpath value to the 2nd template. Would that be possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where is the "xpath as the input"?

Comment: The requirement is like this. I need to pass an xpath as an input parameter  to the xslt. The node corresponding to that xpath needs to be removed from the xml and the resultant xml would be the output of my xslt.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

This is not possible in XSLT 1.0 - unless your processor supports some sort of `evaluate()` extension function.

**Longer answer**:

XPath is much more versatile than your example shows. The same path could be expressed in a variety of ways, for example:

```
/ns1:Student/n2:Details/ns3:Number
ns1:Student[1]/n2:Details[1]/ns3:Number[1]
pf1:Student/pf2:Details/pf3:Number
//ns3:Number[parent::n2:Details]
```

These are all semantically equivalent in the context of the given XML.

In theory, you could construct your own path expression for every node in the given XML and compare it to the given path. In practice, it would require a strict set of rules (much stricter than the XPath language provides) that both you and the path provider would abide by, so that both of you arrive at the exact same string.

---

**Edit**:

I forgot to mention the possibility of using the given path to create a new XSLT stylesheet, then applying the result to the original XML input.

Comment: I just updated the question with whatever I have done till now (apologies as I am not very familiar with this site). Anything that can be done there?

Comment: If the parameter is a string, then I believe those are your only options.  Which processor are you using and how are you initiating the transformation?

Comment: The transformation is being initiated from a BPEL process (Oracle SOA Suite)

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about that.